# Drag item from QTreeWidget to QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview, qtreewidget

I've the following situation:

[image: Example]

Basically I've a `QTreeWidget` with some items, and a canvas that's a subclass of a `QGraphicsView`. What I want to accomplish is to drag a `QTreeWidgetItem` in the `QGraphicsView` subclass. When the mouse is released in the `QGraphicsView` subclass I want to create a new shape (let's say a circle) with some data of the dragged item (let's say the name itself written inside the circle).

I was able to enable the drag from the `QTreeWidget` by using the `setDragEnabled(true)` method, and I'm able to receive the event in the `QGraphicsView`, because when I enter its area it calls the `dragEnterEvent`.

In my subclass I've a `QGraphicsScene`, like this:

```
#ifndef SEQUENCECANVAS_HPP_
#define SEQUENCECANVAS_HPP_

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class SequenceCanvas : public QGraphicsView {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  SequenceCanvas(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~SequenceCanvas() = default;

protected:

  void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event) override;
  void dropEvent(QDropEvent* event) override;

private:

  void createWidgets();
  void createLayout();

private:

  QGraphicsScene m_scene;
};

#endif // !SEQUENCECANVAS_HPP_
```

```
#include "SequenceCanvas.hpp"
#include <QString>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QMimeData>

SequenceCanvas::SequenceCanvas(QWidget* parent) :
  QGraphicsView(parent) {
  createWidgets();
  createLayout();
  setScene(&m_scene);
  setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void SequenceCanvas::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event) {
  event->acceptProposedAction(); // no filter at the moment I just want to test
}

void SequenceCanvas::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event) {
  int i = 0; // just for putting a breakpoint now. Its breakpoint is never raised
}

void SequenceCanvas::createWidgets() {

}

void SequenceCanvas::createLayout() {

}
```

Even if the `dragEnterEvent` is called when my mouse enter my widget during the drag, the `dropEvent` method is not called, so when I release the mouse inside my `SequenceCanvas` class nothing happens.

Basically I've two questions:

- How can I raise the drop event inside my `SequenceCanvas` class that's a subclass of `QGraphicsView`?
- How can I pass custom data (let's say a vector of strings) with the drop event, so I can pass all needed information for managing the event?

EDIT:

I missed to reimplement the `void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)` method. I've added it and now I receive drop events. I need to know how to pass custom data with a drag-drop event now... Thanks to zeFrenchy.

My class body now is:

```
SequenceCanvas::SequenceCanvas(QWidget* parent) :
  QGraphicsView(parent) {
  createWidgets();
  createLayout();
  setScene(&m_scene);
  setAcceptDrops(true);
  bool ok = acceptDrops();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VIRTUAL PROTECTED SECTION                                                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void SequenceCanvas::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event) {
  event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void SequenceCanvas::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event) {
  event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void SequenceCanvas::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event) {
  int i = 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PRIVATE SECTION                                                           //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void SequenceCanvas::createWidgets() {

}

void SequenceCanvas::createLayout() {

}
```

Comment: is acceptDrops set to true on your widget?

Comment: I call `setAcceptDrops(true);` in the `SequenceDiagram` constructor. If I call `acceptDrops()` after it it returns `true`.

Comment: oops, missed that 

Comment: The doc says this about the DragMoveEvent (worth a try just accepting the action): A widget will receive drag move events repeatedly while the drag is within its boundaries, if it accepts drop events and enter events. The widget should examine the event to see what kind of data it provides, and call the accept() function to accept the drop if appropriate.

Comment: I suspect the drag/drop events need to be handled by the viewport rather than the `QGraphicsView` itself.  Try either installing an event filter on the viewport widget or setting your own custom viewport widget that handles the relevant event.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've implemented the `dragMoveEvent` and now I receive the drop event. Now how can I pass custom data?

Comment: Glad I could help a bit, but I believe, there a one question at a time policy in place! 

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer in the event you decide to keep your question as originaly asked.

Comment: @Jepessen, I am having the same exact issue. Did you find a solution to this question? If so could you please share it? I noticed that on the EDITS you asked also another question and did you find an answer to that question too Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says the following about [DragMoveEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdragmoveevent.html):

> A widget will receive drag move events repeatedly while the drag is within its boundaries, if it accepts drop events and enter events. The widget should examine the event to see what kind of data it provides, and call the accept() function to accept the drop if appropriate.

So you should be provide an override for `dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* event)` in which you simply accept the proposed action.